# How to get data from intermediate table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 3 table like this,

**kelas**

> id | kelas | romawi

**jurusan**

> id | alias | motto | visi | misi | tahun

**kelas_jurusan** (intermediate table)

> id | id_kelas (from table kelas) | id_jurusan (from table jurusan)

Update:

**siswa**

> nama_lengkap | nisn | id_kelas_jurusan (from table kelas_jurusan)

I want to get data 'kelas' in table kelas with accessing the kelas_jurusan table in Siswa model.

I have code like this:
**Siswa Model**

```
public function kelas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kelas', 'kelas_jurusan', 'id_kelas');
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, SO is not for writing code for you. Please post code which you have done or try to learn from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. You can define your models as

```
class Kelas extends Model
{
    public function jurusans()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Jurusan::class, 'kelas_jurusan', 'id_kelas');
    }
}

class Jurusan extends Model
{
    public function kelases()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Kelas::class, 'kelas_jurusan', 'id_jurusan');
    }
}
```

To get data from both models you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
Kelas::with('jurusans')
```

---

---

As per your updated structure you need to introduce a new junction model like `KelasHasJurusan` which will have following mappings in it

KelasHasJurusan

```
class KelasHasJurusan extends Model
{
    public function kelas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kelas::class, 'id_kelas');
    }
        public function jurusan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Jurusan::class, 'id_jurusan');
    }

    public function siswas(){

        return $this->hasMany(Siswa::class, 'id_kelas_jurusan');

    }
}
```

Other models will be mapped like

Kelas

```
class Kelas extends Model
{
    public function kelasHasJurusan()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(KelasHasJurusan::class, 'id_kelas');
    }
}
```

Jurusan

```
class Jurusan extends Model
{
    public function kelasHasJurusan()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(KelasHasJurusan::class, 'id_jurusan');
    }
}
```

Siswa

```
class Siswa extends Model
{
    public function kelasHasJurusan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(KelasHasJurusan::class, 'id_kelas_jurusan');
    }
}
```

Now to load data for kelas alongwith siswa data you can get as

```
Kelas::with('kelasHasJurusan.siswas')
```

Comment: how to access from siswa model? example, i want to get "kelas" in table kelas with siswa model

Comment: @AzzarioRazy can you explain what is/how is siswa model  related to kelas model? It would be good if you can update your question

Comment: i trying with : 
public function kelas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kelas', 'kelas_jurusan', 'id_kelas');
    }

its still getting an error

Comment: hello, where i run your code the output is display all record in table kelas, not spesific kelas by id

Comment: @AzzarioRazy use `where()` clause or `find()` method to filter records please have a look at official eloquent or query builder docs for more

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596913/how-to-get-data-with-id-relation-in-intermediary-table-laravel

Comment: this is my new question

Comment: Thanks, i found my answer in view you can put {{ $siswa->kelasJurusan->kelas->kelas }}